# Question about definition of coordinate charts

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

I am having trouble understanding the following question, which I will paraphrase here:

The $n$ sphere $S^n$ is defined: $S^n= \left\{ \textbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^{n+1}: |\textbf{x}|=1 \right\}$. It has an atlas with two charts $\left\{(U_1, \phi_1), (U_2, \phi_2) \right\}$, where $U_1=U_2= \mathbb{R}^n$, $\phi_1(U_1)= S^n- \left\{(-1,0,...,0)\right\}$, $\phi_2(U_2)= S^n- \left\{(1,0,...,0)\right\}$ and $\phi_1, \phi_2$ are the inverses of:

$\phi_1^{-1}: (x_0,...,x_n) \mapsto \frac{1}{1+x_0}(x_1,...,x_n)$

$\phi_2^{-1}: (x_0,...,x_n) \mapsto \frac{1}{1-x_0}(x_1,...,x_n)$

The question then goes on to ask for a proof that this makes $S^n$ into a smooth manifold. My problem is this: I thought that for a chart $(U_i, \phi_i)$ on $S^n$ we must have $U_i \subseteq S^n$, which is clearly not the case if we define $U_i= \mathbb{R}^n$. It seems to me that the definition of these charts is "backwards", i.e. we should have $(\phi_i(U_i), \phi_i^{-1})$ instead of $(U_i, \phi_i)$ for $i=1,2$. Is this the case?

Comment: Yes, these are called parametrizations, and are as you say "backwards charts". Surely it doesn't matter, as the maps between the opens are homeo's.

Comment: Ok, that's what I thought.

Comment: Parametrizations go "up", charts go "down" (thinking of the standard picture)

Comment: Yeah, think of a (geographical) map, which charts a portion of the earth.